# PHP if condition to Array to Foreach

Tags: php

Example code:
HTML-

```
<input type="text" name="title1"/>
<input type="text" name="title2"/>
<input type="text" name="title3"/>
```

PHP
check if above fields has text.

```
$title1 = null;
if ($title1)
    $title1= "'1'";
$title2 = null;
if ($title2)
    $title1= ",'2'";
$title3 = null;
if ($title3)
    $title3= ",'3'";
```

Make Array

```
$titles = [$title1.$title2.$title3];
```

Foreach

```
foreach ($titles as $key=>$title) {
    echo '<p>' . $key.$title . '</p>';
}
```

It's currently printing only first value when title1 and title2 has text. 
Can you tell me what is wrong with above codes? Better solution welcome!

Comment: This is an array with only 1 element `$titles = [$title1.$title2.$title3];`. You need comma's to separate the elements or `explode()` to convert a string in an array.

Comment: That set of IF's makes no logical sense either, unless you intended to make a 3 variables contain NULL

Comment: Please check again, $title1='1' when $title2=,'2'

Comment: Did you move data from `$_GET` or `$_POST` into those variables?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen, I was believing and thinking I did right on this line until I saw and tried butlerblog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is with the following:

```
$titles = [$title1.$title2.$title3];
```

You're assembling the strings together as a string, not an array. So the `$titles` array only has one element.

Try this:

```
$title_str = $title1.$title2.$title3;
$titles = explode( ",", $title_str );
```

That said, it would make more sense to assemble this as you go (in the earlier part of the code block) and I'm not sure how you're actually getting values and why your HTML inputs don't have values, but the above answers your array question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$titles = [$title1.$title2.$title3];
```

This will make array with one element.

How can you expect anything in all title variables if you are assigning them null before?

Comment: I want to add Array items based on user input. So, when title2 or 3 field is empty, don't add any array item. You should understand if you see carefully.